# Unique need for highlighting in asp.net page

Tags: javascript

I am very new to Java script. I am trying to implement a highlighting option through java script in my asp.net page. I need help to write a function for the same as shown below. Here is my java code.

```
var arrKW = Keywords.split(",");
var colr = "red";
var aLen = arrKW.length;

for (j = 0; j < aLen; j++) {
 highlightKW(arrKW[j], colr);
}
```

Explanation: here the variable "Keywords" contain values like "dosage, dose, drug, medicine, medicament". i am trying to split these keywords and store in to an array "arrKW", later on I need to highlight each items in this array with the value stored in the variable "colr".

Anyone please help me to write the code to perform the function highlightKW(arrKW[j], colr).. thanks in advance..

SB

Comment: So you use `java` or `javascript` ?

Comment: i am using javascript.